# oracle apex redirect to modal dialoge page from pl/sql code

Tags: dialog, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a page process in my apex page. I want to redirect to a modal dialoge page after the page process finishes. So I wrote the code

```
htp.init;
owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:34:APP_SESSION.::NO:34:P34_CODE,P34_DAY_DATE:P30_CODE.,'||:P30_DAY_DT); 
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
```

The page 34 is a modal dialoge page . Hence it shows error

> page 34 cannot be rendered successfully. Ensure the page template in use on page 34 is of template type "Dialog page", with appropriate JavaScript dialog initialization, dialog closure and dialog cancel code defined.

Then I tried with

```
 l_url:=APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL('f?p=&APP_ID.:34:APP_SESSION.::NO::P34_CODE,P34_DAY_DATE:P30_CODE.,'||:P30_DAY_DT',p_checksum_type=>'SESSION'); 
 htp.init;
 apex_util.redirect_url(l_url);
 apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
```

That too didn't worked for me. Anybody have solution?

Comment: As per the error message, what is the pag etemplate type in page 34, and what is the JavaScript dialog initialization, dialog closure and dialog cancel code defined in that template?

Comment: page template is modal dialog. JavaScript dialog initialization, dialog closure and dialog cancel codes are default of the application. on page load js is - apex.theme42.initializePage.modalDialog();

Comment: I don't know why you get the error. But why are you using `apex_util.redirect_url` rather than a simple APEX branch?  Does the modal open OK if you use a branch, or does it fail with same message?

Comment: Because I want to pass some values to modal page.That is why I do not use branching.(sorry for the late replies sir, I had bad health condition for last few days)

Comment: Hope you are feeling better now.  But you **can** pass values in a branch, so what am I missing?

Comment: Then that is a good idea I think. But I got an error saying "network protocol violation that cannot be repaired." when I use this method, may be an error from my side. But I got another method using apex_util.prepare_url and js eval() method.

Comment: Sounds like you have a server config issue of some sort, you really shouldn't be having to code round that by not using APEX branches, it needs attending to by whoever looks after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a dynamic action for the button, copy the  pl/sql code in page process and then add an action "execute pl/sql code" in dynamic action.Paste the copied code there.

```
declare
   v_url varchar2(4000);
begin

   v_url:=apex_util.prepare_url
                  (p_url             =>  'f?p=&APP_ID.:34:&SESSION.:::34:P34_CODE:'|| :P30_CNAME,
                   p_triggering_element      =>'$(''#URLS'')'
                  );
   :p30_URL:=v_url;
end;
```

after this pl/sql, create a javascript action for the same dynamic action and write

```
 eval($('#P30_URL').val());
```

eval() is a default js method.This will redirect to modal page