# Oracle apex 5 refresh region/item on parent page after close modal

Tags: javascript, oracle, modal-dialog, oracle-apex

Source: [oracle apex redirect to modal dialoge page from pl/sql code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474907/oracle-apex-redirect-to-modal-dialoge-page-from-pl-sql-code/50897967#50897967)

I need to update the item in the parent window after closing the modal window. The peculiarity is that by pressing the button, the custom JS code (after apex_util.prepare_url (p_url, p_triggering_element) ) is executed and one of the conditions opens the modal window. How can I catch the closing of this modal window? The standard dynamic action "dialog is closed" does not catch this event. According to the assigned J selector # URLS likewise does not work - it is in the HTML page, but not caught through the browser console $ ('# URLS').

Comment: Did you figure out the answer? I'm stuck with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

In the modal page Dialog -> Attributes field put the following javascript code:

close: function(event, ui) {apex.navigation.dialog.close(true,{dialogPageId:(Page number)});}